# Shell Script: value too great for base (error token is "16#?")

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell script. I am working with Hex values and writing a simple script for substraction. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=“0x0001”
var2=“0x0005”
var3=“$(( 16#$var2 - 16#$var1 ))”
echo “Diference $var3”
```

I am getting this error :

```
line 6: 16#?: value too great for base (error token is "16#?")
```

Could you please let me know where my mistake is?

Comment: Please do not cut&paste from editors that mangle ASCII double quotes into  “ and ” UTF-8 opening and closing quotes. This instantly breaks any script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ var1=0x0001
$ var2=0x0005
$ var3=$(( $var2 - $var1 ))
$ echo "Diference $var3"
Diference 4
```

Assign the hex values without double quotes(i.e not as strings).
Since you have already put a `0x` there is no need for `16#`

To conver the answer back to hex you can use:

```
printf '%x' $num
```

Here is an example:

```
$ var1=0x19
$ var2=0xA
$ var3=$(( $var1 - $var2 ))
$ echo $var3
15
$ printf '%x\n' $var3
f
$ var3=$(printf '%x' $var3)
$ echo $var3
f
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and it worked. But can you please assist me that How to get Hex value in var3?

Comment: var1=0x0001
 var2=0x0005
 var3=$(( $var1 - $var2 ))
 var3=$(printf ‘%X’ $var3)
 echo "Diference $var3"

I am getting FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC as answer. Is it correct?

Comment: Shouldn't I get 0x0004 ?

Comment: No, you shouldnt because the `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` is correct. `1-5` is `-4` and `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC` is the hex for `-4`

Comment: Thanks It was my fault.... I have interchanged the values and it is working for that but still I am getting 4 not 0x0004.... How to get 0x0004

Comment: @NiravGadhiya use this instead `printf '0x%04x\n' "$var3"`

Answer (score 3):

`16#` and `0x` are redundant, and mutually exclusive. The problem is that, due to the `16#`, Bash thinks the `x` is trying to be a digit in a base-16 number (whereas it's only valid in base 34 or higher). Just drop either the `16#` or the `0x`, and it'll work.